# Angular 7: Two way databinding on forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I am currently working on one of my first angular projects and I'm struggling to decide on what approach to take best.

The project i'm working on consists out of a form that holds a financial simulation (think of it as putting an xls sheet into an angular app).

Changing values in one form input (xls cell) has to result in other fields automatically being recalculated. These fields can be spread over multiple rows.

Currently I am trying to do this using the reactive forms module, but I'm having trouble responding to events when elements change (as I dont feel like implementing (change) on each field seems like a good idea).

Isn't there some way i can just bind the values to object properties and calculate them this way?

To provide some additional context:
I am creating a profitability simulator for companies that have consultants. 
So each row contains a consultant with its cost, purchase price, daily rate etc.

I was thinking now to switch/refactor to template driven forms to use ([ngModel])...

All suggestions / approaches are very much appreciated!

Best

Answer (score 1):

All controls on reactive forms are observables.  You can subscribe to the form group on changes, and process all changes to the form group, or any nested form group that may exist - and access the changes.  I don't know why ngModel was not supported for reactive forms in Angular 7 - it seems to me to be a bad move.  Many people will be driven away from reactive forms due to this - and that is a shame.

Comment: Reading the reasoning for removing ngModel from reactive form controls - they claim it was due to developer confusion... well believe me, there is much more confusion now about how to achieve two way binding again - and I see huge confusion over this capricious move.

Comment: I am with you on this one. I struggle to come up with a solution to replace ngModel on one my applications where I use a lot of dynamic control creation on the fly and each control two-way binding with the model and the model will be pushed back to the API when submitted. Updating my Angular 6 app to 7 is a nightmare. Really appreciate if anyone could share a cleaner solution for this.